# Counting characters - height and length of a file - C programming

Tags: c, string, loops, char

```
int x;
while((x = fgetc(f)) != EOF){
    if(x[i]!= argv[1]){
        // print error           
    }       
    printf("%c", x);
}
```

Hello people, how do I find how many characters are in the first line of a file? 
and find how many characters are in the first row? argv[1] is required to meet how many chars in the first line, and I have another argv for first row.

Comment: What the execution of the program that you are thinking of your work? ie `./a.out abc def`

Comment: Too many low level errors to fix immediately. `x` is an int, yet you use `x[i]`. `argv[1]` is a char *, yet you (attempt to) compare it to a simple element. In general, your question does not relate to the bad snippet of code.

Comment: after compiled ./example 2 3

Comment: @Sam23yo at the moment, this code does not compile

Comment: Hey @Sam23yo, Please explain what is your exact requirement.Why do you wanna count the number of characters in the file? It will be helpful to guide you.

Comment: You request " how many characters are in the first line of a file? and find how many characters are in the first row?"  The first line of a file is the first row.  These 2 requests seem to be the same.  Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[]){
    FILE *f;
    int i, j, x;
    char first_line[1024];
    f = fopen("data_file.txt", "r");
    fgets(first_line, sizeof first_line, f);//read first line
    fclose(f);
    for(i=1;i<argc;++i){ // for each argv
        int count =0;
        for(j=0;x=first_line[j];++j){
            if(x == *argv[i])//*argv[n] : character of top of argv[n]
                ++count;
        }
        printf("num of %c is %d\n", *argv[i], count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```